# We cannot make react-native-video player to play a video from a API file service

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

Postman or android devices play it nicely, but on iOS platform we are facing the problem. Basically, a user logs in the application and makes a call to API service which returns the mp4 video.Postman header info is also attached. Any help is appreciated.

code is

```
 <Video
            source={{
              uri: "https://api.xxxx.org/v1/files/7afbd0c3-ab0e-4cfb-910a-10c058a07b20"
            }}
            // Can be a URL or a local file.
            controls={true}
            fullscreen={true}
            resizeMode="contain"
            ref={(ref) => {
              this.player = ref
            }}    

          />
```

[postman result is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaCd9.png)

Comment: whats the issue on ios

Comment: I take "AVFoundationErrorDomain code: -11800" error  like on this page           
https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/1317

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.